# Regex: 'exceptions.IndexError: no such group'

Tags: python, regex, json, scrapy

I asked a similar question to this yesterday, but I don't think I gave a very clear explanation of what I wanted to do. I have the following code:

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.item import Item
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
    from scrapy import log
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
    from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
    import time
    import re
    import json
    import requests


    class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "goal2"
        allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
        start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/"]

        rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\Teams'),deny=(),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

        def parse_item(self, response):

            stagematch = re.compile("data:\s*{\s*url:\s*'stage-player-stat'\s*},\s*defaultParams:\s*{.*},",re.S)

            stagematch2 = re.search(stagematch, response.body)

            if stagematch2 is not None:
                stagematch3 = stagematch2.group(1)


                stageid = json.loads(stagematch3)
                stageid = stageid[0]['StageId']

                print stageid
```

With this I am trying to parse some script at this [link](http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/) which takes the format of:

```
data:{
                url: 'stage-player-stat'
            },
            defaultParams: {
                stageId: 9155,
                teamId: 32,
                playerId: -1,
                field: 2
            },
```

From this, I want to extract the value of `stageId`, which in this instance is 9155. This however is throwing up the following error:

```
stagematch3 = stagematch2.group(1)
    exceptions.IndexError: no such group
```

I'm assuming that this is because the regex used is not valid, but I cannot see what the issue is. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  data:\s*{\s*url:\s*'stage-player-stat'\s*},\s*defaultParams:\s*{\s*(.*?),.*},
```

Use this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/4